# translate SNMP MIB into OID

Tags: snmp

Plenty of posts on this subject here but none seem helpful to me. I am interested in creating a Icinga check for "sipUnregistered(19)" so we may know when SIP clients become unregistered to the gateway server. I need the OID for this task.

Here's my MIB:

```
CmaEndpointAlertType  ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
   STATUS        current
   DESCRIPTION   "CMA endpoint alert values."
   SYNTAX        INTEGER
                 {
                    remoteControlBatteryLow(0),
                    credentialsRequired(1),
                    credentialsFailed(2),
                    httpForbidden(3),
                    notResponding(4),
                    heartbeatTimeout(5),
                    gatekeeperStatusUnknown(6),
                    gatekeeperRejected(7),
                    gatekeeperUnregistered(8),
                    directoryStatusUnknown(9),
                    directoryNotRegistered(10),
                    presenceStatusUnknown(11),
                    presenceUnregistered(12),
                    helpRequest(13),
                    mgmtUrlNotSet(14),
                    venusDisconnected(15),
                    venusSoftwareIncompatible(16),
                    sipUriNotProvided(17),
                    sipStatusUnknown(18),
                    sipUnregistered(19)
                 }
```

This syntax is found in the file /etc/snmp/local-mibs/polycom/POLYCOM-CMA-MIB.MIB which after dozens of fruitless attempts to translate the MIB I also copied to /root/.snmp/mibs *and* /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs because [this doc](http://www.net-snmp.org/FAQ.html#How_do_I_add_a_MIB_to_the_tools_) said it may help.
It did not help.

Comment: The above snippet is a module in a MIB, not a MIB.

Comment: snmptranslate -On -IR CmaEndpointAlertType::19
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/irtf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/etc/snmp/local-mibs/accedian:/etc/snmp/local-mibs/acmepacket:/etc/snmp/local-mibs/apc:{a bunch of others}/etc/snmp/local-mibs/netBotz:/etc/snmp/local-mibs/polycom:/etc/snmp/local-mibs/procurve:/etc/snmp/local-mibs/std:/etc/snmp/local-mibs/turin
2017-08-16 07:43:20 Cannot find module (CmaEndpointAlertType): At line 0 in (none)
Unknown object identifier: CmaEndpointAlertType::19

Comment: I managed to find the OID, '.1.3.6.1.4.1.13885.14'.
Now I need to figure out how to use it to let me know when any device becomes unregistered with the SIP server.